# How to make ShareLatex ignore single $?

Tags: sharelatex

Hi I have the following code:

```
\item Copy files from the conf folder in the submission into \path{$SPARK_HOME/conf} folder
```

I have a dollar sign inside the path, the document compiles as expected, but ShareLatex highlights everything after in green.

How to make ShareLatex ignore $ symbol inside the path?

Comment: I don't know in ShareLaTeX & this doesn't work in Kile, but in some editors, adding a commented `$` will allegedly satisfy the syntax highlighter. Kile tries to be clever and ignores the commented code, so I have to think of something else to avoid an all-magenta document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
\path{$SPARK_HOME/conf\iffalse$\fi}
```

The part inside `\iffalse ... \fi` is never executed but should fool your editor that the inline math is ending there.

Another option is to never use `$` there in the first place. As `\path` redefines special characters to typeset them, some more verbosity is needed:

```
\def\dollar{^^d}
\expandafter\path\expandafter{\dollar SPARK_HOME/conf}
```

`^^d` is a TeX variant to input `$`. So we define a macro that expands to this character but has to take care to expand the macro before `\path` starts processing its argument, hence the `\expandafter`s.

Another option does not work for the ShareLatex.

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for. I assume this is a bug and should be seen by the developers of the ShareLatex? How could we ensure this? @siracusa

Comment: @Bato-BairTsyrenov It'd be nice if ShareLaTeX would catch that, but in general it's impossible for an editor to catch all corner cases without re-implementing the whole TeX engine. For example, consider `\@ifnextchar$\doThis\doThat` where `$` isn't even enclosed in braces and so very hard for an editor to be seen as a macro argument.